# Lubuntu 20.04 with NVidia driver - tiny fonts!

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, lubuntu, fonts

Just upgraded to 20.04 from 18.04 **(Lubuntu)** on my media server.

On this machine, I need to use the proprietary NVidia drivers to play videos (slow/choppy playback on Nouveau; smooth using NVidia's VDPAU).

After the upgrade, all looked fine until I switched to the NVidia driver and rebooted.  Since then, the fonts used on the LXDE desktop are horribly small - almost unreadable even on a large TV being used as the monitor.  How do I fix this?   As I recall, the same thing happened when I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 a couple of years ago, but I don't remember how I fixed it back then.  Any help would be appreciated.

The fonts in the terminal app, browsers, etc., are all OK.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You didn't provide any details as to your upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 (ie. was it via re-install?).  The Lubuntu 20.04 release notes (in fact all releases from 18.10 up) have stated "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install*."  https://lubuntu.me/focal-1-released/  Your Ubuntu base supports the upgrade, but LXDE is no longer Lubuntu past 18.04

Comment: If you weren't aware, LXDE uses GTK2 which is almost abandonware, as only the portions used by `gimp` are still supported (until `gimp` completes its GTK3 port, ie. any LXDE function using other parts of GTK2 is calling unsupported code).  LXDE devs now code on LXQt (they joined with RazorQt creating the new LXQt desktop). Yes parts of LXDE were ported to GTK3 but they were dropped & not packaged as won't work with current GTK3 as wasn't maintained as focus moved to Qt5 port.  Other desktops (like XFCE) are now fully GTK3, so be aware that LXDE on 20.04 is using upstream abandoned code..

Comment: Yes, I did it via do-release-upgrade.  This machine has way too many customizations to go through a fresh install and re-installation of all apps and changes without a huge time sink.  Right now, everything is working except NFS and the desktop fonts.  Perhaps just switching over to the Gnome desktop would solve the font problem?

Comment: You can re-install without losing any GUI setup. You just re-install, use existing partitions and do **not** format. It'll note your additional packages, erase system directories, install, add back your additional packages then ask to reboot, not touching any user directory (where user files are) unless you formatted partitions. Yes as system directories are wiped, any configs there will be lost, but that won't impact a Lubuntu or any Ubuntu desktop system (as desktop system, desktop applications store their configs in $HOME which is untouched)

Comment: Thanks, guiverc - appreciate the reply.  Some of the changes on this box are more than just the GUI - some are system-level (e.g. certain users do through a VPN by default, others don't, which took a while to configure correctly; this is only one example).  I may try to copy the boot-drive image to another backup and try it; first I will probably try switching the environment to the Gnome desktop.

Comment: FYI:  If it's primary function is as a media server, I'd avoid GNOME, as it's one of the heavier desktops. Yes you can make the GUI/desktop not start on boot (mitigating much of the resource hit by having the machine start as server only) but if you want the GUI, I'd opt for a lighter desktop (XFCE maybe is next lightest standard supported desktop, but it's not your only option).

Answer (score 2):

Since Lubuntu switched to lxqt instead of lxde, you are probably affected by the same thing I am seeing in KDE. "NVIDIA X Server settings" showed me it had recognised my screen as 52 dpi after the driver installation and the fonts were rendered accordingly.

For me, the fix was to find font settings and check the "Force font DPI: 96" button.